# How do I make SQL data display in descending order by default in CakePHP?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I am currently working with CakePHP and I am having difficulties on how to edit the way it is displaying the data.

For context: This is a CakePHP written website where "keycards" are being checked in and out by multiple individuals. I want to display the data, `date_processed` in descending order on the website.

I want to know how or where I should edit or add the code to make the data display in descending order by default.

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($keycards as $keycard): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$keycard['Keycard']['id']?></td>
    <td><?=$keycard['Keycard']['first_name']?> <?=$keycard['Keycard']['last_name']?></td>
    <td><?=$keycard['Keycard']['staff_name']?></td>
    <td><?=$keycardState[$keycard['Keycard']['signature_type']]?></td>
    **<td><?=$keycard['Keycard']['date_processed']?></td>**
    <?php elseif($keycard['Keycard']['image'] === 'Refer to Manual Keycard'):?>
    <td>Refer to Scanned Key Receipt in THD</td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td><img src=<?=$keycard['Keycard']['image']?> /></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It'll be wherever you read `$keycards`.

Comment: You can fetch data from database using order(['id' =>'DESC']) condition. Also please share your fetching data code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would need to do the next thing in CakePhp.
If you have applied a find function to a certain model, then for sorting out by descending order, you would need to proceed like this:

```
 $keycards = $this->KeyCards->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'signature_type' => 'keycard',
      'id' => $id  
     ),
  'order' => 'id DESC'
 ));
```

Comment: "first" fetches only one record from the database

Comment: Sorry, I already knew that hehe, I didn't see it  and posted it accidentally... I edited the post.

Comment: keyword ```'all'``` is unnecessary in cakephp 3 & 4

Comment: I haven't used Cakephp 3 or 4 unfortunately. As I am working on a project in which we use Cakephp 2.6, I didn't have the possibility to update my knowledge upon deprecated features.